# Matrix size Java

Tags: java

I have a matrix for example 5x10.

```
double[][] matrix = new double[5][10]
```

I would like to know the size of these matrix, But if I do it:

```
matrix.length
```

It only return me columns size: 10

How could I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`matrix.length` gives you the number of rows.

`matrix[0].length` gives you the number of columns (assuming all rows have the same length).

Answer (score 0):

You can get them like this

```
matrix.length
```

and

```
matrix[0].length
```